# Skip duplicated files on copy

Tags: c#

I am moving files from one folder to another `destination1` to `destination2` however if destination2 already has a copy of the file from destination1 I would like to simply skip and continue the copy process rather than overwriting which will take a longer process.
I have already tried: `FileSystem.CopyFile(destination1,destination2, true);`which will overwrite the file. Is there anyway I could get some assistance on accomplishing this please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check whether the file already exists:

```
if(!File.Exists(destination2))
{
    // copy file
}
```

Comment: So what would be the 'else' which would determine the loop to Skip the file.

Comment: you can just use `continue;` but I think there is no need for else. if this is the only code in the loop body

Comment: @Selman22 True if duplication is just for name. If differences within content has to be taken into account it might get a bit more work

Comment: @Selman22 this seems to do the trick jus well, if my program grows in requirement then I will jus add to the loop but thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You told that you want to avoid overwriting, then why you did pass `true` for the last parameter?

Have you tried passing `false`?

```
FileSystem.CopyFile(destination1, destination2, false);
```

As side note, remember that the system will never compare two files in order to know if they are identical and then skip the copy.
If you want to accomplish this behavior, then you have to implement it by yourself, but it would usually be heavier than simply overwriting, due to the need to fully read the destination file, unless you implement some caching mechanism or the destination file is already (and still) in system cache.

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: Yes i did try 'false', however it didnt work as I wanted, however the if(!File.Exists).... Works in the fashion I want

Comment: Your suggestion won't work. If you set the overwrite parameter to `false`, the application will throw an `IOException` exception on duplicate files.